# how can we extrack the values from two different rows in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO1xL.png)

the table avobe show a info that i need to operate, bassically i need to calculate a distance for each location, so i need that perth coordinates will be x1 and y1 and the Karrakatta will have x2 and y2. how can i operate these coordinates to put them in a formula..

Comment: What is the desired output for this sample? Also, it's best to replace pictures with formatted text, and also include your attempts at solving.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
`select station_name || (x*y) as coordinates from Table_name`

if this doesn't work , can you tell me what you want to do exactly ?